# I need when my tables (not one table many tables) get inserted using mysql information schema

Tags: mysql, information-schema

Here is query:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.TABLES T
WHERE T.TABLE_ROWS>0 AND   T.TABLE_NAME  LIKE '%_sales%';
```

Comment: Can you shed some more light on that? you need to what?

Comment: What problem are you having? Note that `table_rows` will not be reliable for InnoDB tables.

Comment: You want an audit trail of inserts to the tables?

Comment: I think, that nobody really understands your question. Please take one more minute to ask properly, if you want a proper solution.

Comment: I need table list from my database.I created many tables like (client1_sales,client2_sales).i need when the sales tables get   inserted .I dont want check in check in each table.I just want tables what are the tables get inserted in between days...

Comment: i Just need a query that what are the tables get inserted on yesterday...

Comment: Do you have enterprise or community edition?

Comment: I dont know..it is Godaddy server...

Answer (score 0):

Use the `UPDATE_TIME` column.

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_ROWS > 0 AND TABLE_NAME LIKE '%\_sales%'
AND UPDATE_TIME > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: See https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=14374. Updating `update_time` was implemented in MySQL 5.7.2, although it doesn't persist across server restarts.